# Difference usage between reduce and reduceRight w Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm a newbie with Underscore.js.

Recently I read the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#reduceRight) about reduce and reduceRight but I couldn't understand what is the difference between the two.

I will appreciate any help and example.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything with the calls?  And is there anything specific you are trying to accomplish?  It is hard to give an answer with such a vague question, make it more pointed and it is much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: many/most? common reductions are actually commutative, so reduceRight() gives the same results as reduce() on things like sum, avg, unique, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `_.reduce` iterates over the collection starting at the first index and finishing on the last index while `_.reduceRight` does the same thing but starts at the last index and finishes on the first index.

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
_.reduce(list, function(memo, item) { memo.push(item); return memo; }, []);
=> ['a', 'b', 'c']
_.reduceRight(list, function(memo, item) { memo.push(item); return memo; }, []);
=> ['c', 'b', 'a']
```